# I found warning in this method. Multiple method named 'state' found?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am new in mac development. Here is my code, but i don't understand this warning. Please help me.

```
  - (IBAction)toggleFiles:(id)sender
  {
NSRect frame = [oWindow frame];
NSRect contentRect = [oWindow contentRectForFrameRect:frame];
float titlebarHeight = NSHeight(frame) - NSHeight(contentRect);

NSSize newSize = [sender state] == NSOnState ? sFilesExpandedSize : sFilesCollapsedSize;
frame.origin.y -= newSize.height - contentRect.size.height;
frame.size = newSize;
frame.size.height += titlebarHeight;

[oWindow setFrame:frame display:YES animate:YES];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:(int)  [sender state] == NSOnState]
                                           forKey:@"DisplayFiles"];
 }
```

Here this warning found- Multiple methods named 'state' found. How to solved this problem. Please help me.

Comment: What is type of sender?

Comment: Duck typing Vs Xcode 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks  bbum. Here is my answer. I solved my problem.

```
- (IBAction)toggleFiles:(id)sender
 {
NSRect frame = [oWindow frame];
NSRect contentRect = [oWindow contentRectForFrameRect:frame];
float titlebarHeight = NSHeight(frame) - NSHeight(contentRect);
   NSCell *cell =sender;
   Bool fleg = [cell state] == NSOnState;
NSSize newSize = fleg ? sFilesExpandedSize : sFilesCollapsedSize;
frame.origin.y -= newSize.height - contentRect.size.height;
frame.size = newSize;
frame.size.height += titlebarHeight;

[oWindow setFrame:frame display:YES animate:YES];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:[fleg
                                          forKey:@"DisplayFiles"];
}
```

I add only (NSCell * )before sender. Thanks .

Comment: For defensiveness, I'd suggest adding `assert([sender isKindOfClass:[NSCell class]]);` on the line before the cast (or after, doesn't matter).

Answer (score 6):

`sender` is typed as `id`.  That means that the compiler will consider all methods ever defined anywhere that the compiler is aware of as the possible set of things that `sender` can respond to.

Unfortunately, there are two `state` methods (or more) declared that have *different argumentation*.   One may return a `BOOL` and one might return an `NSUInteger`, for example.

Thus, the compiler is warning you that calling `state` on a generically typed (`id`) object may produce unexpected results as there is no way to know what the type of the return value might be.

Solution?

Either statically type `sender` to some specific class (i.e. -(IBAction)toggleFiles:(SomeClass*)sender; or typecast the return value.

In either case, add something like `assert([sender isKindOfClass:[ExpectedClass class]);` to that action method to be defensive.

Comment: Also to note, by having sender typed as id it allows you to do things like have multiple controls call the same IBAction method, and then inside the method handle things depending on the class of sender.